# Juniper SRX IPv6-PD update-router-advertisement issues

Tags: ipv6, juniper-junos

I'm trying to get some sweet prefix delegation working on my SRX. My provider offers DHCPv6-PD and gives out /56 addresses. I have done setups using cisco routers and am trying to replicate it onto a juniper. My issue is that on Juniper it seems that I cannot define what prefix out of the /56 goes onto each interface. It appears to use the same /64 for every interface:

```
# run show interfaces terse                           
Interface               Admin Link Proto    Local                 Remote
pp0.0                   up    up   inet     X.X.X.X       --> ISP.ISP.ISP.ISP
                                   inet6    XXXX:YYYY:a000:c000:1::1/64
                                            fe80::de38:e10f:fc78:b2c0
vlan.0                  up    up   inet     10.10.10.1/24   
                                   inet6    XXXX:YYYY:a000:c000:2::1/64
                                            fe80::de38:e1ff:fe78:b2c8/64
```

Relevant configuration:

```
set interfaces pp0 unit 0 family inet6 dhcpv6-client client-type statefull
set interfaces pp0 unit 0 family inet6 dhcpv6-client client-ia-type ia-pd
set interfaces pp0 unit 0 family inet6 dhcpv6-client update-router-advertisement interface pp0.0
set interfaces pp0 unit 0 family inet6 dhcpv6-client update-router-advertisement interface vlan.0
set interfaces pp0 unit 0 family inet6 dhcpv6-client client-identifier duid-type duid-ll
set interfaces pp0 unit 0 family inet6 dhcpv6-client req-option domain
```

Now like I said I am trying to replication configuration from how cisco do it:

```
interface Dialer10
 ipv6 address prefix-from-provider ::1/64
 ipv6 enable
 ipv6 dhcp client pd prefix-from-provider
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
 ipv6 address prefix-from-provider ::1:0:0:0:1/64
 ipv6 enable
```

Which looks like:

```
GigabitEthernet0/1         [up/up]
    FE80::5257:A8FF:FE55:9A81
    XXXX:YYYY:A000:F201::1
Dialer10                   [up/up]
    FE80::5257:A8FF:FE55:9A80
    XXXX:YYYY:A000:F200::1
```

I can't work out for the life of me how to set what assignment each interface should get. Or even what prefix length should be given. It seems to be stuck giving addresses out of the same /64. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the rather lame things about DHCP-PD on the SRX at the moment (still the case in 21.3R1.9):
Junos will allocate /64s sequentially from your /56 delegation to each interface that you configure router-advertisement on.

So, for each "downstream" interface, configure:

```
set protocols router-advertisement interface <interface>
```

and you'll see that Junos allocates them:

```
<your>:<prefix>:0::1/64
<your>:<prefix>:1::1/64
<your>:<prefix>:2::1/64
```

etc.